# Where did the disease come from and why did it disappear?

Tags: plot-explanation, blindness

Does anyone know what is the cause of the disease in the movie *Blindness*? Is it explained any further in the book?

I wonder if there is a plausible explanation why the population lost their sight and recovered it.

Comment: The cause is irrelevant. The point is the breakdown of society etc.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I concur with you, that the breakdown of the society and the ethics and behaviour are the main topic, the context of how the disease appeared and leaves is importa becuase makes the situation look real and allows you to enjoy a comprehensive narrative, otherwise the premise looks fake to me

Comment: IMHO it doesn't need to be explained. Look at COVID-19: after a year we still don't know where it comes from. Same for plenty of other diseases, sometimes despite decades of research. Or look at a movie like Night Of The Living Dead: whatever caused the zombies is unimportant. There doesn't need to be a "plausible explanation".

Comment: FYI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindness_(novel)

Comment: @BCdotWEB You accidentally put your answer in the comment box again.

Comment: Despite what the comments and their accompanying votes might suggest, your question is indeed reasonable and interesting, specifically because it opens up to interesting answers as to what the point of the desease was and why it *isn't* explained.

Comment: The vote is not "accompanying" my comments. I did not vote on this question. I haven't seen the movie nor read the book, so I'm not inclined to answer, not in the least because I don't see the point of these kind of "everything needs to be explained" questions.

Comment: Judging from your answer-comments, the point in this case seems to be to explain *why it doesn't need* to be explained, which in turn "adds to the appreciation of the film", as the site mantra puts it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No explanation of the origins of blindness was given in the book.
Quoting from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindness_(novel)) Wikipedia article:

> Blindness is the story of an **unexplained** mass epidemic of blindness
> afflicting nearly everyone in an unnamed city, and the social
> breakdown that swiftly follows.